# Flutter Page reloads when keyboard opens or closes

Tags: flutter

I am working on a chat page using flutter so the page structure is

```
Container(
      color: color,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
              itemScrollController: _itemScrollController,
              itemPositionsListener: _itemPositionListener,
              initialScrollIndex: _messages.length - 1,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: false,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) => GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onTap: () {
                  print("tapped");
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                },
                child: ChatMessage(
                  message: _messages[index],
                ),
              ),
              itemCount: _messages.length,
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 1.0,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32, left: 8, right: 8),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
            ),
            child: _textComposerWidget(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

The problem is when click on `textFrom` or when keyboard opens or closes the page reloaded and i loss every data in the `listView` and in the `textForm()`

Answer (score 0):

Need more info, seems like you are using StatelessWidget instead of Stateful

Comment: actually it was my problem i was doing the android way of nav drawer one activity and fragments and change fragments accordingly in flutter i was doing one scaffold with drawer and changing the body widget  of scaffold this way causes the above issue i don't know why this issue happen so i solve it by navigating to a new page or scaffold

Comment: so if you had fixed it - mark issue as closed and put your working code here to help another people